# AngularJS : How to get value and label of a select?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a select tag with a ng-model attribute. I get the value of the selected element in ng-model. How is it possible to also get the label of the selected element.
I would like to retrieve both the label and its value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are either using ng-repeat to create your choices, or typing them manually in the template. It is possible if you set your labels and values in the same model. If you have:

```
$scope.choices = {
    "choiceone" : "The first Choice",
    "choicetwo" : "The second Choice",
    "choicethree" : "The third Choice"}
```

You can implement them like so:

```
<select ng-model="choice">
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in choices" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

**However**, this isn't the best way to use the select directive (assuming this is what you are doing). The select directive has a ng-options attribute that defines both value and label, in a cleaner fashion. I've edited the doc's example Plunkr on this subject, including a example usage of a ngRepeat here: http://plnkr.co/edit/sjQuhlgBh8WWJJoaSSMG?p=preview

Check here for the docs on the ng-options attibute: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select